# Parse cloud code - issues with promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, underscore.js, parse-cloud-code

Here is my code

```
Parse.Cloud.define('filters', function(request, response){
var _ = require('underscore');
var customerGeoPoint = request.params.geolocation;
var rating = request.params.rating

var finalList = [];
// var arr = [];
var promises = [];
var query = new Parse.Query('ServiceProvider');
query.withinMiles("geoLocation", customerGeoPoint, 10);

query.find().then(function(spobjs){
  return spobjs
}).then(function(newval){   
   var query2 = new Parse.Query('Customer');
   for(i in newval){
     query2.withinMiles('geoLocation', newval[i].get('geoLocation'), newval[i].get('serviceRadius'));
     var sp = query2.first()
       if(sp != null)
       {
         finalList.push(newval[i]);
       }
   }
   return finalList ;
}).then(function(resval){
    var arr = [];
    var arr = _.sortBy(resval,'averageRating'); ** This Line doesn't work **
    console.log(arr[0]);
    return arr ;
}).then(function(checkval){

    response.success(checkval);

},function(error){
    // console.log(error);
    response.error(error);
});

});
```

In the above code the line which reads "This Line doesn't work" does nothing. I have required `underscore.js` but still it doesn't sort the array. `finalList` value gets returned to the `then` `promise` after but it doesn't sort it and returns the same value as `finalList`. Can someone tell me what's the issue with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sorting parse objects with underscorejs, the iteratee must return the value of the attribute using `get()`...

```
var arr = _.sortBy(resval, function(o) { return o.get('averageRating'); });
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works now :) . This iteration thing is only for sort or also other functions in underscorejs with parse?

Comment: Glad to help.  Anyplace where you're passing an array of parse objects to an underscore function, and where that function offers a nice shortcut of an attribute name in place of an iteratee, you'll be stuck writing an iteratee function, since underscore doesn't know that you're really passing backbone objects.